# The CBN_SELCHANGE notification not works when i use the function ComboBox_SetCurSel

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a ComboBox in a window and i want to execute a function after changing selected item. 
When i change the selected item of the combobox by mouse or keyboard,
the `CBN_SELCHANGE` event in the window message `WM_COMMAND` works well  and my function execute.

But if i use the function `ComboBox_SetCurSel` for changing the selected item ,it not works.

What window message `WM_****` and combox notification do i use for processing the event changing selected item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, when you *programmatically* manipulate a control, the corresponding notification is *not* sent to its parent. The notification only gets sent when the *user* manipulates the control.

So, when you call `ComboBox_SetCurSel` (which is a macro that performs the same task as sending the `CB_SETCURSEL` message), that programmatically changes the control's current selection and therefore does *not* send the `CBN_SELCHANGE` notification. However, `CBN_SELCHANGE` *does* get sent if the user changes the combobox's selection.

This is called out explicitly in the "Remarks" section of [the documentation for `CBN_SELCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775821.aspx):

> The `CBN_SELCHANGE` notification code is not sent when the current selection is set using the [`CB_SETCURSEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775899.aspx) message.

To work around this, you can do one of two things:

1. Call your event-handler method directly. For example, in MFC, you would have the framework attach an `OnCbnSelChange` member function to handle the combobox's `CBN_SELCHANGE` notification. After your code that called `ComboBox_SetCurSel`, you would simply call that `OnCbnSelChange` member function manually:

   ```
   ComboBox_SetCurSel(hwndComboBox, 0);  // select 1st item
   this->OnCbnSelChange();               // invoke the change event-handler
   ```

   Your GUI framework undoubtedly has something similar.
2. Manually send the `CBN_SELCHANGE` notification to the control's parent. I don't really know why you would ever do this, because the default window procedure doesn't do anything interesting upon receipt of this notification; you would be much better off just calling your own handler directly.

   ```
   ::PostMessage(hwndParent,
                 WM_COMMAND,
                 MAKEWPARAM(IDC_COMBOBOX, CBN_SELCHANGE),
                 reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(hwndComboBox);
   ```

   Or, if you were doing this from a subclass of the combobox:

   ```
   HWND hwndParent = ::GetAncestor(hwndComboBox, GA_PARENT);
   int  ctrlID     = static_cast<int>(::GetWindowLongPtr(hwndComboBox, GWLP_ID));
   ::PostMessage(hwndParent,
                 WM_COMMAND,
                 MAKEWPARAM(ctrlID, CBN_SELCHANGE),
                 reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(hwndComboBox));
   ```

Comment: "I don't really know why you would ever do this, because a combobox's default window procedure doesn't do anything interesting upon receipt of this notification" But you're not sending the message to the combobox, you're sending it to the combobox's parent, which has the code to handle the notification. Careful not to confuse yourself with all this terminology =P (I'd personally spell that code example out in relation to the combobox rather than its parent: `SendMessage(GetAncestor(hwnd, GA_PARENT), WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_ID), CBN_SELCHANGE), (LPARAM)hwnd);`)

Comment: @and You're right, throwing in "a combobox" there doesn't make any sense. I should have just said the default window procedure. And I suppose it would make sense to show how to do this in terms of the combobox, too. I figured someone reading the could easily extrapolate from the facts provided.

Comment: The combobox contains some numbers that are id of colors.When my program runs ,it load the last value of combobox that selected by user and has saved.The value is current-sel and used  for getting color of my color-table and finally is used for background of any object.
I had problem in initializing.
If you have any better idea please guide me.

Comment: @sae I cannot understand from your comment what the problem is. You had a problem in initializing? What problem? What code did you use, and what went wrong? Ask a new question about it if you can't make it work.